# pyTelegramBotAPI get_updates() functiom

Tags: python, dictionary, object, get

My purpose of using `get_updates()` function is to handle pending request from user when I restart my bot from crash or temporary bot shut down.

When resume my bot I want to make sure no repeated request attempt from user during down time, I need to handle those request to avoid duplicate entry.

I am able to retrieve the pending request using get_updates() funtion.

```
pending_updates = bot.get_updates()

for pending_request in pending_updates:
    print('Pending Request', pending_request)
```

the return value is as below

Pending Request {'update_id': 268581735, 'message': {'content_type': 'text', 'id': 492, 'message_id': 492, 'from_user': <telebot.types.User object at 0x00000255A7BA0E20>, 'date': 1625846407, 'chat': <telebot.types.Chat object at 0x00000255A7BA0FD0>, 'forward_from': None, 'forward_from_chat': None, 'forward_from_message_id': None, 'forward_signature': None, 'forward_sender_name': None, 'forward_date': None, 'reply_to_message': None, 'via_bot': None, 'edit_date': None, 'media_group_id': None, 'author_signature': None, 'text': '20', 'entities': None, 'caption_entities': None, 'audio': None, 'document': None, 'photo': None, 'sticker': None, 'video': None, 'video_note': None, 'voice': None, 'caption': None, 'contact': None, 'location': None, 'venue': None, 'animation': None, 'dice': None, 'new_chat_member': None, 'new_chat_members': None, 'left_chat_member': None, 'new_chat_title': None, 'new_chat_photo': None, 'delete_chat_photo': None, 'group_chat_created': None, 'supergroup_chat_created': None, 'channel_chat_created': None, 'migrate_to_chat_id': None, 'migrate_from_chat_id': None, 'pinned_message': None, 'invoice': None, 'successful_payment': None, 'connected_website': None, 'reply_markup': None, 'json': {'message_id': 492, 'from': {'id': 1569061133, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Jian Ming', 'last_name': 'Shen', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': 1569061133, 'first_name': 'Jian Ming', 'last_name': 'Shen', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1625846407, 'text': '20'}}, 'edited_message': None, 'channel_post': None, 'edited_channel_post': None, 'inline_query': None, 'chosen_inline_result': None, 'callback_query': None, 'shipping_query': None, 'pre_checkout_query': None, 'poll': None, 'poll_answer': None, 'my_chat_member': None, 'chat_member': None}

I try to access the data using `dict()` `get()` methods, but it show error.

> print('Pending Request', pending_request.get('update_id'))
> AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'get'

I don't understand the data I get is dictionary or not?

Comment: it may have function `__str__` which displays it as directory but it doesn't mean it has to be directory. You could use `dir(pending_request)` or `help(pending_request)` to see what variables and functions you have in this object. Maybe it has `pending_request.update_id` instead of `pending_request.get("update_id")`.

Comment: thanks I am able to get the update id through pending_request.update_id